# Same encryption algorithm, same input, different result

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I use this for security in a windows application, and it is important that if a user encrypts the same string they get the same result as any other user who encrypts the exact same string. I have been using this routine for 5 years in a windows application. Almost all the time, this works perfectly. However once in a great while, I will get a user who does not get the same result as everyone else.

In the code below, I changed the sEncriptKey and sInitVector values, however the values I am using are of the correct length and made up of simple just alpha numeric characters that never change. Also, sText is usually pretty small, like 8 to 30 characters.

Thanks for the help.

```
public static string EncryptString(string sText) {

   string sEncriptKey = "012345678901234567890123456789AA";// 32 Chars
   string sInitVector = "0123456789ABCDEF"; // 16 Chars;

   byte[] oByteArrayText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sText);

   System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sInitVector);
   byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sEncriptKey);
   CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateEncryptor(key, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

   cs.Write(oByteArrayText, 0, oByteArrayText.Length);

   cs.Close();

   return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: A few questions: Where does the string `sText` come from in the application? Does the user type it in somewhere? Are you sure that the users in question aren't using a different codepage, so that even though they appear to enter the same string, it's actually not mapping to an identical `sText` in your function?

Comment: Can you reproduce this "once in a while" behaviour when you replace your users with a ConsoleApplication1-loop? Or does that only happen with user input?

Comment: Seems to be there is something with process.may be it change the text value which has to encrypt in the process of that user. otherwise the code is ok.

Comment: While this is pretty weak encryption, I don't see why it should produce differing outputs.

Comment: Just some time ago I had somebody who had a similar issue, seemed that some invisible (white space) characters were part of the input. Even BOM can be part of the string. Unicode can be "funny" like that - so test your input!